# TypeError: graphql.e is not a function

Tags: typescript, graphql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmbba.png)

I'm trying to add wallet connect provider to my project but after so many tries stuck at one of this error which is not getting by me.

Project's discription:
node version: 14.18.3
next: 9
typescript: 5
webpack: 4

I have custom webpack also where i added more loaders.

below code is for next.config.js

```
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withVideos = require("next-videos");

module.exports = withVideos(
  withImages({
    fileExtensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif","svg"],
    env: {
    },
    webpack(config, options) {
      if (!options.isServer) {
        config.resolve.alias["@sentry/node"] = "@sentry/browser";
      }
       // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module      
        if (!options.isServer) {
          config.node = {
              fs: "empty",
            };
        }
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /node_modules[\\/]@walletconnect/,
          loader: require.resolve('esbuild-loader'),
        })
      return config;
    },
    pageExtensions: ['tsx', 'jsx', 'js']
  })
);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "decentraweb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.3",
    "@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.33",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.61",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "babel-plugin-relay": "^10.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "babel-preset-es2020": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-materialize": "^0.22.0",
    "expose-loader": "^1.0.3",
    "relay-compiler": "^10.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "ts-loader": "^8.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "test": "npx hardhat test",
    "relay": "relay-compiler --schema schema.graphql --src ./ --language typescript --customScalars.AccountRelayID=String --customScalars.Address=String --customScalars.AssetBundleRelayID=String --customScalars.AssetRelayID=String --customScalars.AssetContractRelayID=String --customScalars.ChainIdentifierScalar=String --customScalars.CollectionRelayID=String  --customScalars.CollectionSlug=String  --customScalars.Date=String --customScalars.DateTime=String --customScalars.JSONString=String --customScalars.OrderRelayID=String --customScalars.PaymentAssetRelayID=String --customScalars.PaymentAssetSymbol=String --customScalars.RelayID=String --customScalars.URL=String",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/blk-design-system-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/blk-design-system-pro-react.css",
    "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/blk-design-system-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/blk-design-system-pro-react.min.css --output-style compressed",
    "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/blk-design-system-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/blk-design-system-pro-react.css --source-map true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@0xproject/assert": "^1.0.13",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.2",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^2.1.6",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.1",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.2.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.27.6",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.27.6",
    "@sentry/node": "^5.27.6",
    "@types/chai": "4.2.9",
    "@types/fbemitter": "^2.0.32",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.4",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.92",
    "@types/node-fetch": "2.5.5",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.12",
    "@types/relay-runtime": "^10.1.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.4.2",
    "@walletconnect/ethereum-provider": "2.9.0",
    "@walletconnect/modal": "2.6.0",
    "accept-language": "^3.0.18",
    "agent-base": "^6.0.2",
    "amplitude-js": "^7.3.3",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.3",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^4.5.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "console": "^0.7.2",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "dd-trace": "^0.29.1",
    "debug": "^4.3.1",
    "dweb-nft-js": "git+ssh://git@github.com/decentraweb/dweb-nft-js.git#cart-develop",
    "esbuild-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",
    "ethers": "^5.4.1",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.6.4",
    "headroom.js": "0.11.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "ipfs-http-client": "50.1.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "mocha-typescript": "^1.1.15",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "next": "9.5.5",
    "next-images": "^1.6.2",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "next-videos": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.0",
    "nouislider": "14.2.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "pickadate": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "rc-slider": "^9.6.5",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap-switch": "15.5.3",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.2",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-fullstory": "^1.4.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.14",
    "react-markdown": "^5.0.3",
    "react-materialize": "^3.9.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-relay": "^10.1.2",
    "react-relay-network-modern": "^6.0.0",
    "react-relay-network-modern-ssr": "^1.4.0",
    "react-router": "5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.4",
    "react-select": "3.1.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-tagsinput": "3.19.0",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "8.4.1",
    "read-file": "^0.2.0",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "relay-compiler-language-typescript": "^13.0.2",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^6.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^4.1.1",
    "typedoc": "^0.11.1",
    "types-bn": "^0.0.1",
    "types-ethereumjs-util": "0.0.8",
    "typescript-eslint-parser": "^16.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "walletlink": "^2.0.2",
    "web3": "^0.20.7",
    "web3-typescript-typings": "^0.9.3",
    "web3modal": "^1.9.4"
  },
  "main": "_app.tsx",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```